# Can not find where to override ShouldRestoreState in PrismAutofacApplication

Tags: prism

I have a PrismAufofacApplication and I can not find where to override the ShouldRestoreState method from Prism.Windows.PrismApplication.

Answer (score 0):

You override it in the App.cs file.  The method is defined in the base PrismApplication class.  It's is virtual and can be overridden:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/PrismApplication.cs#L333

Comment: I do not have an app.cs file (sorry I've inherited this project from another dev). I have an app.xaml.cs file whose class is defined as:
`public sealed partial class App : PrismAutofacApplication`
yet when I add
`protected override bool ShouldRestoreState(IActivatedEvertArgs args)
{
return false;
}`
I get the error "no suitable method found to override"